# How to specialize protocol method on Swift Generic Type?

Tags: swift

```
struct Point<T> {
    var x: T
    var y: T
}

extension Point: CustomStringConvertible  {
    var description: String {
        return "\(x), \(y)"
    }
}

// error: Conflicting conformance of 'Point<T>' to protocol 'CustomStringConvertible'; there cannot be more than one conformance, even with different conditional bounds
extension Point: CustomStringConvertible where T == Double{
    var description: String {
        return String(format: "%.3f, %.3f", x, y)
    }
}
```

```
print(Point(x: 1, y: 2)) // output: 1, 2
print(Point(x: Double(1.111111), y: Double(2.222222))) // expected output: 1.111, 2.222
```

How do I specialize the `CustomStringConvertible.description: String` method for `Double` type?

The compile error shows I cannot extend the same protocol twice.

Trial 1:
If I removed the extending syntax `: CustomStringConvertible`, it compiles. But the `Point<Double>.description` will NOT be called when calling `print(Point<Double>(...))`.

Trail 2:
If I add a `where T == Int` at first extension, the same compile error shows.

What is the correct way to specialize extension method in Swift?

Comment: You cannot override standard library behavior. Why do you want to do that? Seems a bit like an XY problem.

Comment: I want in general case `String(Point)` gives "\(x), \(y)". And for floating number `Double` type, `String(Point)` gives "%.3f, %.3f", only holding 3 digits after dot.

Comment: And why don't you just explicitly convert Double to such a string in Point.description?

Comment: I don't want generic Point know about the type `Double`. So I expect I can define separated extension only for `Point<Double>`. 

Because I can do something like the following in C++, I am curious the whether similar way exists in Swift.
`template<typename T> std::string Point<T>::get_str() { return "..generic.."; }`
`template<> std::string Point<double>::get_str() { return "..only for Double..";}`

Comment: So this is indeed an XY problem. You can certainly achieve the same thing in Swift. Just not by overriding standard library behavior (which your C++ doesn't do either, by the way.) I'll write up an answer to address your actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

`CustomStringConvertible` is a protocol, and it requires a conforming class/struct to adopt a property called `description`.

The compiler shows you this error because **your only one generic type struct** `Point` tries to create/implement this required property of this protocol **twice**.
You can't do that. Your struct conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` and it requires only 1  `description` property to be implemented.

So in your case, I would do the following:

[image]

Before `description` property returns something, it can have a basic if-else check.

Comment: I am sorry. In this particular example, I wanted to show that the code prints multiple examples fine. But sure, I will keep your comment in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Swift doesn't have the same concept of specialization as C++ does. Please see my very recent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806647/calling-non-generic-function-from-generic-context-swift/65807135#65807135) that explains some differences to C++ template programming.

On the other hand, protocol specializations are only dispatched statically, so they would not work they way you want them, even if your code was allowed. Please see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809411/why-is-generic-specialization-lost-inside-a-generic-function).

Swift relies on an more traditionally object-oriented approach, which features explicitly spelling out contracts by the means of protocols (which is not common in C++).

You want T to be convertible to a string according to your rules. So define a protocol for that:

```
protocol PointStringConvertible {
    var pointString: String { get }
}

struct Point<T: PointStringConvertible> {
    var x: T
    var y: T
}
```

Now implement PointStringConvertible for Double:

```
extension Double: PointStringConvertible {
    var pointString: String {
        String(format: "%.3f", self)
    }
}
```

Use your new protocol in Point:

```
extension Point: CustomStringConvertible  {
    var description: String {
        "\(x.pointString), \(y.pointString)"
    }
}
```

And it'll work:

```
print(Point(x: 12, y: 43))
```

prints `12.000, 43.000`.

However, this won't work for types that do not conform to your protocol:

```
print(Point(x: true, y: false))
```

will error. In my mind, that makes a lot of sense.

You can extend all types that conform CustomStringConvertible to easily implement PointStringConvertible for other types:

```
extension PointStringConvertible where Self: CustomStringConvertible {
    var pointString: String {
        description
    }
}

extension Bool: PointStringConvertible {}
```

But of course, this still requires declaring conformance, which is not a bad thing. If you don't like that, you can still do this:

```
struct Point<T> {
    var x: T
    var y: T
}

extension Double: PointStringConvertible {
    var pointString: String {
        String(format: "A double %.3f", self)
    }
}

extension Point: CustomStringConvertible  {
    private func pointString(for val: T) -> String {
        (val as? PointStringConvertible)?.pointString ?? "\(val)"
    }

    var description: String {
        "\(pointString(for: x)), \(pointString(for: y))"
    }
}

print(Point(x: 12.0, y: 43.0))
print(Point(x: true, y: false))
```

Giving:

```
A double 12.000, A double 43.000
true, false
```

Whether this is good design is another question. Note that you could, of course, also simply switch upon the type of T:

```
struct Point<T> {
    var x: T
    var y: T
}

extension Point: CustomStringConvertible  {
    private func pointString(for val: T) -> String {
        switch val {
        case let double as Double:
            return String(format: "A double %.3f", double)
        default:
            return "\(val)"
        }
    }

    var description: String {
        "\(pointString(for: x)), \(pointString(for: y))"
    }
}

print(Point(x: 12.0, y: 43.0))
print(Point(x: true, y: false))
```

But this probably constitutes knowledge of Double in Point.