# Why is generic specialization lost inside a generic function

Tags: swift, generics

When I create a computed property that depends on a generic type, the specific implementation is "lost" when the instance is passed in a generic function.

For example, I added the `isBool` on `Array` that returns `true` if `Array.Element` is `Bool`:

```swift
extension Array {
    var isBool: Bool {
        false
    }
}

extension Array where Element == Bool {
    var isBool: Bool {
        true
    }
}
```

Using it directly on the instance works fine

```swift
let boolArray: [Bool] = [true, false]
let intArray: [Int] = [1, 0]

boolArray.isBool // true
intArray.isBool // false
```

But inside a generic function it always uses the non specialized implementation:

```swift
func isBool<Element>(_ array: [Element]) -> Bool {
    array.isBool
}

isBool(boolArray) // false, instead of true
isBool(intArray) // false
```

This is not a real use case so I don't really need a way to "fix" this, but I would like to understand why it behave like that.

Comment: I don't have a good explanation but note that here `extension Array where Element` the type Element is from the definition of Array but in your function declaration Element is a new type that just happens to have the same name. So Element != Element

Comment: Indeed, but inside `isBool(boolArray)`, `Element.self == Bool.self` and `type(of: array) is Array<Bool>.Type` are both `true`. So at this point, I think it should be able to get the more specific version of `.isBool`.

Comment: Have a look at this https://nomothetis.svbtle.com/the-ghost-of-swift-bugs-future?utm_campaign=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly&utm_medium=web&utm_source=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_203. (I hope that's the link I was thinking of.) It's not exactly your issue, but closely related. I'll try to write up an answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specialization is not a replacement for inheritance. It should be used to improve performance, not change behavior.

For example, `distance(from:to:)` is usually O(k), where *k* is the distance. For RandomAccessCollection it can be performed in O(1) due to a specialization. But the result is the same either way.

Specialization is done at compile-time based on the information the compiler has. In your example, the compiler can see that `boolArray` is a `[Bool]`, and so it uses the specialized extension. But inside of `isBool`, all that the compiler knows is that `array` is an Array. It doesn't know *when compiling the function* what kind of Array will be passed. So it picks the more general version to cover all cases.

(The compiler may create multiple versions of `isBool` in the binary for optimization purposes, but luckily I haven't found any situations where this impacts what extensions or overloads are called. Even if it actually creates an inlined, Bool-specific version of `isBool`, it will still use the more general Array extension. That's a good thing.)

Leaving your extensions in place, the following would do what you expect (though I don't encourage this):

```
func isBool<Element>(_ array: [Element]) -> Bool {
    array.isBool
}

func isBool(_ array: [Bool]) -> Bool {
    array.isBool
}
```

Now `isBool` is overloaded and the most specific one will be selected. Within the context of the second version, `array` is known to be `[Bool]`, and so the more specialized extension will be selected.

Even though the above works, I would strongly recommend against using specialized extensions or ambiguous overloads that change behavior. It is fragile and confusing. If `isBool()` is called in the context of *another* generic method where Element is not known, it again may not work as you expect.

Since you want to base this on the runtime types, IMO you should query the type at runtime using `is`. That gets rid of all the ambiguity. For example:

```
extension Array {
    var isBool: Bool { Element.self is Bool.Type }
}

func isBool<Element>(_ array: [Element]) -> Bool {
    array.isBool
}
```

You can make this much more flexible and powerful by adding a protocol:

```
protocol BoolLike {}
extension Array {
    var isBool: Bool { Element.self is BoolLike.Type }
}
```

Now, any types you want to get "bool-like" behavior just need to conform:

```
extension Bool: BoolLike {}
```

This allows you all the flexibility of your extensions (i.e. the `isBool` code doesn't need to know all the types), while ensuring the behavior is applied based on runtime types rather than compile-time types.

---

Just in case it comes up, remember that protocols do not conform to themselves. So `[BoolLike]` would return `isBool == false`. The same is true for an extension with `where Element: BoolLike`. If you need that kind of thing to work, you need to deal with it explicitly.

```
extension Array {
    var isBool: Bool {
        Element.self is BoolLike.Type || Element.self == BoolLike.self
    }
}
```

Comment: "Specialization is done at compile-time based on the information the compiler has". Is there any way to "force" the `.isBool` go through dynamic dispatch (not necessarily in the context of an `Array`, maybe it's easier with a class)? Side note, I'm not planning on using any of this in a real world project, i'm just curious of why Swift behave like that.

Comment: Nothing that I can think of in this case. You can force dynamic dispatch in an `@objc` class, but those can't be generic. And creating the same method in multiple extensions in undefined behavior anyway (in both Swift and in ObjC).